# Can I copy the stock firmware from my Oppo A31 (CPH2015) from the phone to a laptop?

Tags: rooting, device-firmware, oppo

I am trying to root an Oppo A31 (CPH2015) but I require the stock firmware of the phone to be available on a laptop such that I can extract from it the boot.img file and then flash it with Magisk.

I am wondering whether there is a way to copy the exact firmware of the phone to a laptop.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. There's an existing Q&A that explains the procedure to root an Android device thoroughly, including extracting the firmware. Hope that helps!